# Australian visa -Global processing time is exceeded but no response from consultate?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, australia

I'm asking this question on behalf of my colleague.

He applied for an Australian visa on 29th may 2019. It has been more than 25 days (over 7 days of global processing time). But there's no response from the consulate yet.

we, inquired the consulate regarding and received a response "Your application is a rare case and we're still processing your application".

My question is, is it possible to get in-depth details of his application? If so, How?

Comment: No. You will not get more information, nor him. And which kind of information you will think to get? He should just wait.

Comment: Close voters, please not that the question is "Can I find out why the application is being delayed?", not "Why is the application being delayed?" We are _not_ being asked to read the minds of the visa officers.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there aren't any max processing times listed on the Home Affairs website. The way times are stated is:

75% of applications processed within X days
90% of applications processed within Y days

Those values are indicative only and are not a guarantee. By definition 10% of all applications take longer.

Did your friend apply online? If so you can check his immi account for any updates or requests for more information or documents.